# Packet Structure at Each Layer of Stack Wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, packets

Ive recently been given a networks assignment but i'm stuck with no idea how to complete it.
The assignment is to use wireshark to identify the exact structure of the packets at each of the layers?? Showing addressing at different layers, purpose of the various frames and their sizes
Ive been looking at ways how but theres not much? Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wireshark` capture can give data link layer, the network layer, the transport layer, and the actual data contained within the frame.

1. On the capture, you can find packet list pane which displays all the captured packets. Select one frame for more details of the pane.
2. The packet details pane gives more information on the packet selected as per `OSI` layer by expanding and collapse.

Check out the [webpage](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/use-wireshark-to-inspect-packets-on-your-network/3871/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Would you know of any tutorials on this subject??